Model performing poorly after cross validation
After using cross-validation to see how a custom predictive function performs on unseen data, I applied to function to the original dataset, and the performance (based on coefficient of determination) massively decreases.
I'm trying to build a predictive model to take 3 input features and predict a proportion. I defined a custom function to bound the output between 0 and 1:
def xg_curve(X, a, b, c, d, e):
     x1, x2, x3 = X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:, 2]
     return 1 / (1 + a * b ** (c * x1 + d * x2 + e * x3))

I attempted stratified 5-fold cross validation, by ordering the dataframe by the target variable, then assigning them 0-4 cyclically, which had the distribution of the target across all folds nearly identical to each other, and the dataset as a whole.
The mean R2 for test fold was 0.6485, and very tightly clustered around this value across all folds, with mean training R2 equal to 0.655 and also very tightly clustered around this value.
It’s quite a small dataset (750 entries) so I used cross-validation to ensure the model generalises to unseen data well, rather than just performing well on one particular train/test split. The model is predicting a difficulty rating for a shot to be saved in an ice-hockey simulator, so I want to apply it to the shots already programmed (the dataset) and any future shots made for the game. The target is the percentage of the time the existing shots have been saved by users.
Based on domain knowledge, I was happy with around 65% of the variability in the target accounted for by the features, and applied the function to the dataset as a whole. However, when I did this, the R2 value dropped to 0.478. I have provided my code below, I can't spot any mistakes! Any help would be massively appreciated!
def xg_curve(X, a, b, c, d, e):
    x1, x2, x3 = X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:, 2]
    return 1 / (1 + a * b ** (c * x1 + d * x2 + e * x3))


    X_data = over50[["Required_rate_of_closure", "Shot angle", "Lateral_diff_spin"]].values
    y_data = over50["Goal Percentage"].values
    folds = over50["Fold"].values

    # Initialize lists to store RMSE and R^2 for each fold
    train_rmse_values = []
    train_r2_values = []
    test_rmse_values = []
    test_r2_values = []
    params_list = []

    # Number of folds
    k = 5

    for i in range(k):

        # Split the data into training and testing sets
        train_idx = folds != i
        test_idx = folds == i
    
        X_train, X_test = X_data[train_idx], X_data[test_idx]
        y_train, y_test = y_data[train_idx], y_data[test_idx]
    
        # Fit the model on the training set
        popt, _ = curve_fit(xg_curve, X_train, y_train, p0=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
    
        # Predict on the training set
        y_train_pred = xg_curve(X_train, *popt)
        # Predict on the testing set
        y_test_pred = xg_curve(X_test, *popt)
    
        # Calculate RMSE and R^2 for training set
        train_rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_train, y_train_pred))
        train_r2 = r2_score(y_train, y_train_pred)
    
        # Calculate RMSE and R^2 for testing set
        test_rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_test_pred))
        test_r2 = r2_score(y_test, y_test_pred)
    
        # Store the results
        train_rmse_values.append(train_rmse)
        train_r2_values.append(train_r2)
        test_rmse_values.append(test_rmse)
        test_r2_values.append(test_r2)
        params_list.append(popt)

    # Calculate mean and standard deviation for RMSE and R^2 across all folds
    mean_train_rmse = np.mean(train_rmse_values)
    std_train_rmse = np.std(train_rmse_values)
    mean_train_r2 = np.mean(train_r2_values)
    std_train_r2 = np.std(train_r2_values)

    mean_test_rmse = np.mean(test_rmse_values)
    std_test_rmse = np.std(test_rmse_values)
    mean_test_r2 = np.mean(test_r2_values)
    std_test_r2 = np.std(test_r2_values)

    print("Training RMSE: Mean = {:.4f}, Std = {:.4f}".format(mean_train_rmse, std_train_rmse))
    print("Training R^2: Mean = {:.4f}, Std = {:.4f}".format(mean_train_r2, std_train_r2))
    print("Validation RMSE: Mean = {:.4f}, Std = {:.4f}".format(mean_test_rmse, std_test_rmse))
    print("Validation R^2: Mean = {:.4f}, Std = {:.4f}".format(mean_test_r2, std_test_r2))


    final_params, _ = curve_fit(xg_curve, X_data, y_data, p0=[1,1,1,1,1])

    a,b,c,d,e = final_params

    print(f' Final Parameters: a = {a}, b = {b}, c = {c}, d = {d}, e = {e}')

    print(r2_score(xg_curve(X_data, *final_params), y_data))
```

